# testing plupload with capybara, send_keys not generating FilesAdded event

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

I am trying to test plupload drag drop event with capybara. Normal workflow is

1. user click/ ( or can drop file) on upload-area
2. local OS window opens up
3. click on file, press ok
4. file is attached
5. plupload generates 'FilesAdded' event (that does some magic)

Now in case of capybara here are the steps

```
filename = '/Users/name/full/path/file.pdf'
visit upload_document_path
element = find('#browse-button')
value = element.send_keys file
```

now these steps do attach the file but plupload is not generating the 'FilesAdded' event if someone has faced such problem then please let me know,
Thanks.

Comment: What driver? What version of Capybara? Is '#browse-button' actually the input[type='file']  element?
What makes you say it is actually attaching the file?
What event is pulpupload looking for to trigger generating its own  'FilesAdded' event?

Comment: selenium, capybara (2.7.1), <input type="file" id="browse-button" />, drag-drop file or attach file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using plupload (since I can't find any project online called pulpulpoad) then it's looking for a 'change' event to be fired to cause the triggering of its own FilesAdded event - https://github.com/moxiecode/plupload/blob/master/js/plupload.dev.js#L1064 .  With Capybara you should be calling

```
attach_file('browse-button', file)
```

which in the end boils down to send_keys, but prior to that does a few checks to make sure it can work properly.

If that doesn't work for you and you're using selenium-driver 2.53.4 and FF <= 47.0.1 then you need to post the error you're getting and a sample of the html.  If you're using selenium-webdriver 3.xx beta and FF >= 48  then you're probably running into this bug - https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/168 - which apparently is solved in FF 49.0.1

Comment: I am using 
selenium-webdriver (2.53.4), FF (47.0)
but to my surprise attach_file is showing the same behaviour as send_keys i.e. just attaching the file but not generating the event.

Comment: Assuming you mean FF (47.0.1) then you either have an event handler that is swallowing the change event and preventing plupload from seeing it, or you have a JS error in your code that is preventing plupload from attaching its event handlers in the first place

Comment: I changed my driver from selenium to poltergeist and every thing worked fine but more importantly it was Tom's answer about using attach_file instead of send_keys, so selecting this as an answer. Thanks.